# In how many ways is it possible to send three people three different types of postcards each from a store that sells $10$ types?

Tags: combinatorics

Good day,

I would have a question.

If in the store is $10$ types of postcards ("infinitely many") How many possibilities are there to send to three people three different types of postcards each?

Am I right is it $3 \cdot C(3,10)$ (three times, combinations three out of 10)?

Comment: Do you mean each person receives one post card or each person receives three post cards?

Comment: Each person recieve three diffetent postcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider first, sending three different postcards to one friend, there are $ 10 \choose 3 $ ways of doing this.

To answer the question with three friends, you are simply choosing 3 different postcards three times. Hence there are $ \left[ {10 \choose 3} \right]^3 $ ways of choosing three different postcards to go to three different friends.